# Debuging Pico W

Tags: pi-pico

I have followed the instructions for using openocd to debug an program, but the output I get from openocd is:

```
Info : Hardware thread awareness created
Info : Hardware thread awareness created
Info : RP2040 Flash Bank Command
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : BCM2835 GPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : clock speed 1001 kHz
```

Note that

```
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

is missing.

The command line I have used is:

```
openocd -f interface/raspberrypi-swd.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg
```

Was wondering if the fact that I am using a PicoW effects the raspberrypi-swd config?

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like pin #25 was faulty use wiringPi gpio toggle 6 (#25) with an LED to confirm.  Modified raspberrypi-swd.cfg, rebuild openocd and all works fine now.

Comment: Just a reminder that if you change the config file, you need to rebuild.  From the openocd directory, use `make clean`, then `make` then `make install`.  When that is complete, reboot the pi.